# Redireccionar para otra pagina utilizando AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, django

Una función *AJAX* al cual le paso una lista que contiene el `id` de las filas seleccionadas de una tabla y dos valores de tipo `date` que son la fecha inicial y la fecha final. Esos valores los proceso en una vista que tengo desarrollada con *Django*. Yo quiero que después que yo trabaje con esos datos el resultado final, devolverlo como un contexto de datos para la página a donde voy a redireccionar.

El problema es que no puedo redireccionar a no ser que en mi función del `succes` ponga `window.location = response.url`, y de esa manera no puedo pasarle un contexto de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Si devuelves la dirección desde Django dentro de un json

```
data = {
    'key': '0',
    'value': 'direccion',
}
```

Y si la petición es correcta, se obtiene el valor de la url.

```js
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'url', 
        data: { }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var url = ""
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    url = element.value
            });
            if(url != "")
              window.location = url
        }
    });
```

Espero haberte ayudado.